# What is the grammatical name and function of the highlighted expression

Tags: phrases, nouns

What is the grammatical name and function of the highlighted expression in the sentence below: We attended **the wedding ceremony**

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: Noun phrase and as object of the verb 'attended'

Answer (score 0):

I should start off by saying that Stack Exchange websites aren't meant for people to answer homework questions or questions that have little to zero thought involved. As user *Bitter dreggs* commented, see how this website works and then perhaps rephrase your question.

To answer your question, "the wedding ceremony" is a **common noun**. In particular, the common noun in question is the "ceremony". The "wedding" part is merely describing what *type* of ceremony it is. A wedding is also in and of itself a common noun, but in this case, since it is describing another noun, it is an *attributive noun*.

Comment: And its function is the object of the verb "attended".